# Cant start Oracle DB due to control file errors

Tags: oracle, startup

I'm trying to start Oracle db, but it yields an error which is shown below:

[image]

I have checked the control_files and these are listed below:

[image]

Check the accessibility of both files:

```
       $ ll /app/oracle/oradata/ENOVIA/control01.ctl
       ls: cannot access /app/oracle/oradata/ENOVIA/control01.ctl: No such file or directory
       $ ll /app/oracle/oradata/ENOVIA/control02.ctl
       ls: cannot access /app/oracle/oradata/ENOVIA/control02.ctl: No such file or directory
```

Error alert log file:

```
  ORA-00210: cannot open the specified control file
  ORA-00202: control file: 
  &apos;/app/oracle/oradata/ENOVIA/control02.ctl&apos;
  ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
  Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
  Additional information: 3
  ORA-00210: cannot open the specified control file
  ORA-00202: control file: 
  &apos;/app/oracle/oradata/ENOVIA/control01.ctl&apos;
  ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
  Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
  Additional information: 3
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Has this previously worked, on this server? If so what changed since it last worked, and when/why did it go down? If not then where has it come from - have you just copied some files from another machine? You haven't told us anything about the environment or history, and without knowing how you got to this situation it's hard to tell you how to get out of it. Assuming it worked until recently and just based on that error, are all the expected filesystems mounted?

Comment: You need the control files. Do you have a backup? (Preferably RMAN). Are they anywhere on the machine? (Try: `find / -type f 2>/dev/null | grep ".ctl$"` )